# links in bootstrap column are not fully clickable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Only a small portion of the link is clickable(say half) and the other half is not recognized, but when I remove the `class="linksdiv"`, they are clickable fully.

```css
#linkshead{
  margin-left:60px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:100px;
  padding:0;
 }
.linksdiv{
  margin-left:60px;
  width:150px;
  margin-top:10px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family:Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div id="linkshead">Quick Links</div>
      <div class="linksdiv">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a> </li>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your links working correctly and it's all clickable, regardless you have missed two closing `</div>` tag at the end of your code

Comment: FYI: You linked the `Bootstrap 3` css, but the question is tagged as `Bootstrap 4`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i figured out, error was something else. The width of columns I was using wasn't sufficient, so half of the links came out the column, so I adjusted it.